Continue process while waiting in simpy
In simpy I simulate a car driving day and night. As soon as my tank fills below 70% and it is daytime I go to fill up. If my tank gets below 70% at night I just drive on and go fill up as soon as it gets light. I know in advance when it gets light. So I can compute beforehand how many hours (dt_hours) I must wait till daylight. My gasoline consumption depends on my speed and route, which are determined in the simulation. My desired output is the place where I refuel and the amount I need to refuel. If I put
yield env.timeout(dt_hours)

in my simpy driving process, the driving halts and my car does not drive on, but the position remains constant. My question is how can I just drive on in simpy, determining my speed and route, while waiting for it to get light?

Sounds like you need two processes where a sunrise process "interrupts" a driving process.

can you post some code as a example?

@Michael Your suggestion of a sunrise process interrupting the driving process works!
